# My app builds successfully but crashes while running with "Invalid application ID."

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, android-studio

Logcat

```
----------    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7447)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6964)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6870)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2106)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7815)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to find your app ID.                                                       *
    ******************************************************************************
    
    
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzt.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:24)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:3)
        at android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       package="com.dating.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.dating.app.Main.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/flirt_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/flirt_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Settings.NotificationActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Start.RemindActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Start.StartActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Settings.SupportActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Settings.PasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Settings.EmailActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Settings.AccountActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Settings.ReportActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Profile.ProfileEditActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Main.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Start.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Start.RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Message.MessageActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Profile.ProfileActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Settings.SettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Settings.PrivacyActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Accounts.AccountsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dating.app.Premium.PremiumActivity" />

        <service android:name="com.dating.app.Extra.ServiceClass" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_banner_ad_unit_id" />


        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>
     </application>

</manifest>
```

gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dating.app.flirt.chat"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.2"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.0.1'
    implementation "com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:2.3.2"
    implementation 'link.fls:swipestack:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:placeholderview:1.0.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.mindorks.android:placeholderview-compiler:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.6'
    implementation 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.2.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.3'
    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: hi, upload here manifest, build.gradle files etc.

Comment: i updated the manifest and the build gradle please take a look

Answer (score 0):

If this line showing correct thing that you added `admob banner ad unite id` there. then change it asap with `admob app ID`

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="@string/admob_banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

ad unite and app ID is different thing, app ID used to initialize Ads SDK on startup,
ad unite used to load and manage ADS.

open your `google admob account` > `select the app` > click on `ad units`
then click on any of your ad unite name,

in top right you will be able to see a button says `Implementation instructions` like image bellow. click that and copy application ID [image: Screenshot]